# UDP port binding by multiple applications?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to bind multiple applications running on different PCs across a single LAN. Is it a good idea when all applications are receiving on same port and sending at same port?

For example:

- app1 (receiving at port 10000, sending to some ip2 and port 10000)
- app2 (receiving at port 10000, sending to some ip1 and port 10000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but not recommended.
 The ports should be configurable anyway, so that you can for instance different ports for test and production.
There are enough free ports available anyway and then it is easier if every app has its unique port.